# Quaternions in Standard Form

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

> Let 
>   $1=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    1 & 0 \\
>    0 & 1 \\
>   \end{array} } \right],\ 
> i=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    i & 0 \\
>    0 & -i \\
>   \end{array} } \right],\ 
> j=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    0 & 1 \\
>    -1 & 0 \\
>   \end{array} } \right],\ 
> k=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    0 & i \\
>    i & 0 \\
>   \end{array} } \right]$.
>   Show that $\alpha=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
>    a+bi & c+di \\
>    -c+di & a-bi \\
>   \end{array} } \right]$ may be written in the form $$\alpha=a1+bi+cj+dk$$

So is this because $a\cdot 1 + b \cdot i$ is the first spot in $\alpha$? I can see that $i^2, j^2, k^2$ are all going to give me $-1$.

Comment: If you know how to multiply a matrix by a scalar (in the way intended here) then there is no big mystery.

Comment: Well apart maybe from the broken assignment defining $i:=\mathrm{diag}(i,-i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's because\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}a+bi&c+di\\-c+di&a-bi\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}bi&0\\0&-bi\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&c\\-c&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&di\\di&0\end{bmatrix}\\&=a\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}0&i\\i&0\end{bmatrix}\\&=a1+bi+cj+dk.\end{align}